# How to fail the Azure pipeline if any errors are reported in the task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

Pipeline is not failing even though the application errors are reported in one of the task. For that i have used failonstderr: true in the pipeline and pipeline detects the errors and start failing. But the problem is failing the pipeline for warnings also. But i am looking for the pipeline should fail when errors are reported[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DagEA.png) not on warnings. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: could you share the yaml task please ?

Comment: You could inject a fail action on your build script for errors. for example using powershell you could add `exit 1` in order to fail your pipeline based on a condition. This way you can skip warnings and exit only on errors

Comment: Unfortunately i cant able to share the yaml  pipeline script. If  I use exit 1 in my yaml script the task/stage automatically will fail irrespective of the result.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the control option of each task by disabling `Continue on error` and running this task `Only when all previous tasks have succeeded`. Then, if any errors are reported in the task, the pipeline will fail. Please refer to [Task control options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#task-control-options) for more information.

[image]

As for YAML pipeline, please make sure you have added `continueOnError: false` to you task. Alternatively, make sure you haven't added `condition: expression` to each task. Then, it defaults to `Only when all previous task have succeeded.`

Comment: I have tried this one. The problem is  the pipeline is successfully executing all the tasks/stages even though the output is not expected/ with errors. I  need to fail the pipeline when the errors are reported in the task. The task/stage should fail and should not proceed to next task/stage

Comment: Hi @sr123, have you enable this setting for each task? Whether you are using Classic or YAML pipeline? Please share your pipeline definition and a screenshot of the pipeline run log.

Comment: Hi @Suki Ji-MSFT. Unfortunately i cant able to share my script. Thanks for the suggestions. Currently i am using yaml Pipelines. Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: Hi @sr123, I have edit the answer, please check if you have set any condition in YAML. Besides, when running the pipeline, are the jobs running one by one in order or disorder? Is the failed task is the one which run last?